# How to configure a CEPH host with public and private NICs

Tags: networking, ceph

So here is the situation. I am deploying CEPH on a public cloud using cephadm.

I am trying to create a private,public network config as described [here](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rados/configuration/network-config-ref/#network-configuration-reference)

First we bootstrap the monitor with

- `ceph boostrap --mon-ip <public_addr> --cluster-network <cluster_subnet>`

Then add subsequent hosts with

- `ceph orch host add <hostname> <private_addr>`

Now I would like to access my CEPH cluster from the public network

ik i can set public_addr for OSDs using:

- `ceph config set osd.n public_addr <addr>`

how to do that for the *host* itself

**I.E**: how can I tell CEPH to that the following host has **2 IP addresses**

something like: `ceph orch host add <hostname> <public_addr> <private_addr>`.

So that for mon daemons and whatever else `cephadm` decides to spawn/move it can use the correct public and private IP address for the daemon on that host

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but ceph only knows about two networks, public and cluster. All clients go through the public network and contact the OSDs via public network as well. The cluster network is only required if you really need to separate the replication traffic between OSDs. All other networks you want to add to your hosts are not managed by cephadm. Just configure the interfaces as required and you're good to go.